# Cannot Delete(Mapping) an object of my DB with POSTMAN

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity named Player and other one named Game, every player have X games, so Games have a foreign key for idPlayer.
I'm trying to delete a Player with all his GamesTries, logically, and spring says "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dices`.`game`, CONSTRAINT `FKss1l3mwkp44i09b7j2rolnyp5` FOREIGN KEY (`player_id_player`) REFERENCES `player` (`id_player`)) ", and POSTMAN says through JSON: "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement".

Here is the code of both entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_player")
    private Integer idPlayer;
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime registerDate;
    private float successRate;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(Integer idPlayer, String name, LocalDateTime registerDate, float successRate) {
        this.idPlayer = idPlayer;
        this.name = name;        
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
        this.successRate = successRate;
    }

//getters n setters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_game")
    private Integer idGame;
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_player")
    private Integer idPlayer;
    private Integer valueDice1;
    private Integer valueDice2;
    private boolean won;

    public Game() {
    }

    public Game(Integer idGame, Integer idPlayer, Integer valueDice1, Integer valueDice2, boolean won) {
        super();
        this.idGame = idGame;
        this.idPlayer = idPlayer;
        this.valueDice1 = valueDice1;
        this.valueDice2 = valueDice2;
        this.won = won;

    }
//getters n setters
}
```

And then the Player Controller and  Player Service

```
//CONTROLLER
    @DeleteMapping("dices/players/id")
    public void deletePlayerById(@RequestBody Player player){
        playerService.deletePlayerById(player.getId());
    }

//SERVICE
    @Transactional
    public void deletePlayerById(Integer id) {
        gameRepository.deleteByIdPlayer(id);
        playerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

Many thanks to yall!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to have a player foreign key inside game, just add a @ManyToOne RelationShip:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idPlayer;
    private String name;
    private LocalDateTime registerDate;
    private float successRate;

    public Player() {
    }

    public Player(Integer idPlayer, String name, LocalDateTime registerDate, float successRate) {
        this.idPlayer = idPlayer;
        this.name = name;        
        this.registerDate = registerDate;
        this.successRate = successRate;
    }

//getters n setters
}
```

and for the game you can have this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idGame;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="player_id", nullable=false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Player player;

    private Integer valueDice1;
    private Integer valueDice2;
    private boolean won;

    public Game() {
    }

    public Game(Integer idGame, Integer idPlayer, Integer valueDice1, Integer valueDice2, boolean won) {
        super();
        this.idGame = idGame;
        this.idPlayer = idPlayer;
        this.valueDice1 = valueDice1;
        this.valueDice2 = valueDice2;
        this.won = won;

    }
//getters n setters
}
```

so now if you delete the player, OnDelete annotation will delete the orphan games along with your player. I don't know why you tried JoinColumn like that. it is worth noting that you can model this as bidirectional as well and use orphan removal capability set to true. you can read about it more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)